# How the long lives of oil platforms can account for the volatility in oil prices?

Tags: self-study

I have a question that asks me to explain how the fact that oil rigs/platforms last for a very long time increases the volatility in oil prices.

To me this does not make sense (I just can't understand how having a long lasting asset, effectively making their operations more efficient and less costly, could possibly increase the volatility of prices)

Any help would be amazing, thank you :)